# Is the MERGE command in PostgreSQL atomic or does it need some "love" like the SQL Server version?

Tags: sql, postgresql, stored-procedures, merge

Coming from SQL Server where I know that the `MERGE` command needs some extra care like locking hints to be an atomic operation, I now take my fist steps with PostgreSQL. I now came to a point where I would like to use a MERGE command in PostgreSQL, knowing the problematic in SQL Server, I did a quick research and looking at the docs to see if the `MERGE` command in PostgreSQL is atomic by design or if something similar like on SQL Server is needed.

If it makes any difference the command will not be used directly but within a stored procedure. Currently using PostgreSQL 15.

Well I did not find an answer, only some blogs that mention something in the flow of text but nothing concrete.

### Clarification

"Atomic was a bit short what I meant was ACID, so let me rephrase `MERGE` in not ACID. `MERGE` acts like multiple statements run one after another and it is not guaranteed that every operation of this single command is made against the same version of the data. Because other statements can modify them in the meantime. A single `UPDATE` statement (without sub selects of course) is ACID because as soon as the statement is starting to execute the underlying data will not be changed by other statements until the `UPDATE` statement is finished.

Comment: Can you upgrade to Postgres 16?

Comment: _"knowing the problematic in MSSQL"_ - While T-SQL's `MERGE` certainly has under-documented _gotchas_ - I wouldn't describe it as being "problematic".

Comment: @Dai No, upgrade is not possible at the moment

Comment: Provided your procedure does everything in a well-structured `TRANSACTION` (with the right isolation level) I think you'll be okay. Though always check the plan with `EXPLAIN` (and other commands/tools) just to make sure. Don't forget to also explore [Postgre's error/warning callback system too](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ecpg-errors.html).

Comment: All statements are atomic in the transactional sense. Can you tell us what exactly you mean by "atomic"? Showing your actual statement and describing the desired behavior would help.

Comment: Read in [Transaction Isolation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/transaction-iso.html) the section that starts *MERGE allows the user to specify various combinations of INSERT, UPDATE and DELETE subcommands ...*

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe While it is granted that for example that `UPDATE` is atomic even if multiple ROWS are updated at once. `MERGE` on the other hand on SQL-Server is not atomic you can have all kinds of lock and deadlock situations basically exactly the same problems you run into of you use a `SELECT` statement following by `INSERT`, `UPDATE` and/or `DELETE`.

Comment: @Dai  : SQL Server's MERGE statement has had more horrible bugs than just about any feature in the last 30 years!  Admiitedly, many are now fixed: https://sqlblog.org/merge

Comment: You have to be even clearer. How does a deadlock compromise atomicity? You can have locks and deadlocks with a simple `UPDATE` too. Please turn your vague feeling of "has issues" into something precise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you run `MERGE` on the default `READ COMMITTED` isolation level, concurrent data modifications can lead to transaction anomalies like "lost update". The statement will always be atomic in the sense that it either completes successfully or has no effect.

Note that that is not substantially different from an `UPDATE`: see for example [this article](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/transaction-anomalies-with-select-for-update/). And you can have things like that happen with a single `UPDATE` that modifies several rows.

The only reliable way to avoid anomalies is to use a higher transaction isolation level: `SERIALIZABLE` if you need absolute certainty, but usually `REPEATABLE READ`, which prevents lost updates from concurrent data modifications, is good enough.

The alternative is to lock everything in sight, which is usually undesirable.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the link [@Adrian Klaver](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6464308/laurenz-albe) has provided [Transaction Isolation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/transaction-iso.html) I found the answer I was looking for.

Based on this documentation `MERGE` statement in PostgreSQL is also not ACID. They stated clearly that **rows could be modified between the SELECT phase and the INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE phase which can lead to unwanted results if the INSERT, UPDATE and DELETE parts also involves conditions**.

So in short you will have to be extra careful when using MERGE and choose the right isolation level based on the use case just like in MS SQL Server.